# Eyes controller doesn't generate after clicking ''Re-generate rig''

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have this problem: When I add armature (metarig), position it in my character and use the rigify re generate rig the eye controls doesn't appear.
I look at the metarig and apparently the bones are there but when I hit regify (generate rig) they are not generated!!(?) I look at the list called WGTS_rig and they are not there either.

Is there a solution for this? Sorry if I didn't understand it, is the first time I use the rig system. Hopefully there is a good solution, I wouldn't like to re position all the bones.
Here some screenshots comparing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bj6a.jpg
English is not my native Language so if there was any confusion I am very sorry for that.

Comment: Please add your images directly into your question rather than making us go to an external link to view them. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something went wrong during face bones editing: some bones got deleted, wrongly renamed, or placed in unappropriate locations (you have to preserve joints that are in the same exact spot, even thoose which are not connected each other).

The fastest way to solve is to create  a new Metarig, activate the snap vertex function, which works even for bones, activate the stick viewport display on one of the Metarigs.

In this way, hiding the meshes, it's fast and easy to snap the new Metarig onto the old one, and maybe during the process you will find out where some bones that should have stayed in the same spot have been accidentaly moved away one from the other.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to cry,  thank you very much indeed, that was really frustrating me, I assumed the problem was something related to that and I didn't want to do it all over again but with the vertex snap it was much faster and it worked perfectly thank you very much.